# Remove files of specific file type as soon as the file appears

Tags: linux, bash, file, loops, rm

My company's program generates lots of data with many different file types. One of them, `.log` file type uses much space and since I do not need log files I would like to remove them as soon as the program creates them. Unfortunatelly I cannot disable log creation option, as the program simply does not offer such an option. I wonder: is running `find` with `-delete` option in a `while true` loop best option, or is there any better/recommended option?

```
while true
do
    find -type f -name "*.log" -delete
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `incrond` daemon to listen filesystem changes and delete file when it appears or just use cron to delete *.log files in every minute as more simpler solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you have [inotify-tools](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=inotify-tools) (which should be part of every Linux distribution) installed, this script will block-wait for file-creation events and remove the corresponding files:

```sh
inotifywait -e create --monitor --format "%w%f"  ${YOUR_LOG_DIR} | egrep --  line-buffered "\.log$" \
        | while read -r file; do
            rm -v $file;
          done
```

Comment: Does it work also for log files stored in different subdirectories of main log directory?

Comment: Yes, there is a `--recursive` Option for `inotifywait`: https://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait